# SSL Test for the server domain (not a web app domain)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Let's say you have a server which resolves to `myserver.company.com` and on that server you run two web applications under the domains `app-a.company.com` and `app-b.company.com`. If I use LetsEncrypt to issue certificates for `app-a.company.com` and `app-b.company.com` I get the A+ score on Qualys SSL Test.

When I run the same test for `myserver.company.com` it doesn't find a matching certificate because there's obviously no certificate issued for that domain, it simply presents the first found certificate. Do I just leave that as is or should I do something about that as well?

Comment: Are you planning to put a web site there? What do you want to happen to traffic that reaches that hostname?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, no, I only use that domain to ssh to the server, but there won't be anything behind that domain itself. I think I'm a bit confused by a security audit I received and in it they referenced the `myserver.company.com` domain as having invalid SSL, but I don't quite understand why they would test it seeing as there's nothing really behind it.

Comment: Probably because you gave the machine that name. In any case the test result is bogus if the name is not in use.